# Why does PHP strlen() return negative length?

Tags: php, string, debugging

[`strlen($str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is returning negative values for a "huge string" that is created using [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_STRICT|E_ALL);
echo phpversion(); // 5.3.26
echo PHP_INT_MAX; // 9223372036854775807
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
$str = str_repeat('a', 2 * $gb);
echo strlen($str); // gives int(-2147483648)
echo $str[0]; // Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

$str2 = str_repeat('a', 4 * $gb);
echo strlen($str2); // gives int(0)

$str3 = str_repeat('a', 123 + 4 * $gb);
echo strlen($str3); // gives int(123)

$str4 = str_repeat('a', 6 * $gb); // starts to wrap again...
echo strlen($str4); // gives int(-2147483648)
echo $str4[0]; // Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

$str5 = str_repeat('a', 123 + 8 * $gb);
echo strlen($str5); // gives int(123)

?>
```

Is this behavior defined?

Or is this a PHP bug?

Comment: Looks like you ran into the maximum integer value on 32bit PHP. A 64bit server would report the accurate length.

Comment: As strlen returns an integer value, and all integers in PHP are signed integers, and 32-bit PHP uses 32-bit signed integers, then it is implicitly defined. The constant PHP_INT_MAX gives you the upper limit, whereupon the value "wraps" and goes negative

Comment: My PHP_INT_MAX reports 9223372036854775807...

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php (and note this: `When PHP.net states "Note string can be as large as 2GB." php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php do they mean it can go over 2GB? – Pacerier Jun 6 at 14:49`

Comment: I see this behavior on 64 bit PHP.  1024*1024*1024 = 1073741824, 107374182*2 = 2147483648 but `strlen()` reports that same value with the sign flipped negative.

Comment: @fvu, yes *I'm* testing that behavior right now.

Comment: I'm getting same output as OP on 64 bit PHP. `PHP_INT_SIZE` === 8.

Comment: What if you use something other than var_dump? Or var_dump a comparison to zero?

Comment: @jcsanyi Doing `echo strlen($str)` will report the same negative value as var_dump() here...

Comment: What happens if you do one minus 2GB? `$str = str_repeat('a', 2 * $gb - 1);` Currently, you have the 32nd bit set, `0b10000000000000000000000000000000`, one minus clears that top-most bit to give you `0b01111111111111111111111111111111`, also known as 2147483647. If you get the correct value out (2147483647), then my guess would be they're using signed integers instead of unsigned for the length of the string.

Comment: @nickb, `2 * $gb - 1` works as expected (thus we get length 2147483647, as documented in PHP manual). The problem is shouldn't strlen report the length as zero instead of negative?

Comment: Documented return of 0 for strlen() is only for empty strings: there is no specifically documented behaviour for strings that exceed signed 32-bit integer length; but expected behaviour would be the same as adding to "wrap" from positive to negative: the puzzle (for me) is why it's using 32-bit ints instead of 64-bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [`string` can be as large as 2GB.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

It looks like it is in fact (2GB - 1). This works fine on my x64 box:

```
$str = str_repeat('a', 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 -1);
echo $str[0];
```

... while this breaks:

```
$str = str_repeat('a', 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
echo $str[0];
```

What you are doing is simply *undefined*, and the manual should be corrected. I would have expected a warning too.

Interestingly, this raises a fatal error:

```
$str = str_repeat('a', 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 -2); // 2GB - 2 bytes
$str .= 'b'; // ok
$str .= 'c'; // PHP Fatal error:  String size overflow
```

---

**Update:**

The [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65239#1383898028) has been attended to. Documentation on php.net has been fixed and now writes "2147483647 bytes maximum".

Comment: I followed your suggestion and submitted the bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65239

Comment: Yea for some reason even though `echo $str[0];` doesn't work, the string still takes memory and we can operate on it (using trim etc).

Comment: @Pacerier You may want to add the test case with the string concatenation to your bug report, it seems to support the idea that this is a documentation bug. Besides `str_repeat` should probably throw the same fatal error as when concatenating.

Comment: at least `str_pad` does exit with error. I think it's more than a documentation bug, it's essentially a `str_repeat` bug. I don't think there's another function that allows us to create strings of length > 2147483647 is there?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're simply overflowing an int with your large string. From a manual:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

So it should be OK if your string size can fit into int.

Comment: There's no integer overflow, my PHP_INT_MAX reports 9223372036854775807

Comment: Read the [manual for strings](http://php.net/language.types.string). It doesn’t matter what the maximum integer value is if strings have a different limit.

Comment: @Gumbo, strlen() returns an int. So you're bounded to int limit in what you can return from strlen. It doesn't matter what limit strings have.

Comment: @Jk1 [PHP uses `int` internally](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#478) which can only represent values up to 2^31-1.

Comment: @Gumbo, that's the implementation of zend server, but it does not mean all PHP implementations need follow that right?

Comment: @Pacerier The Zend engine is the platform PHP is build on.

Comment: @Gumbo, What about HHVM?