# How to Catch a String Overflow Error in PHP, or how to prevent it?

Tags: php, string, memory, phpexcel

I have the following error:

```
Fatal error: String size overflow in /Users/jMac-NEW/Word_trial/PHPExcel_1.7.8-
with_documentation-msoffice_format/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php on line 233
```

The original code is PHPExcels's *OLERead.php*:

```
$block = $bl;
$data = '';

while ($block != -2)  {
    $pos = ($block + 1) * self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE;
    $data .= substr($this->data, $pos, self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE); // this is line 233
    $block = $this->bigBlockChain[$block];
}
return $data;
```

The API for this code reads:

```
/**
 * Read a standard stream (by joining sectors using information from SAT)
 *
 * @param int $bl Sector ID where the stream starts
 * @return string Data for standard stream
 */
```

How do I either catch this error or prevent it? Try catch doesn't work (bec fatal error?)
I also refer to the answer in [PHP Excel Memory Limit of 2GB Exhausted reading a 286KB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545217/php-excel-memory-limit-of-2gb-exhausted-reading-a-286kb-file), which stated that what was "causing the memory overflow was [an .xls file] downloaded in ASCII mode instead of Binary". However, instead of downloading via FTP as per the situation in that post, I retrieved the files using RecursiveDirectoryIterator and RecursiveIteratorIterator. Apparently the file's size I am working with is 28956bytes, very similar situation to that post. But in my case how do I make the change of downloading to Binary VS ASCII?

Please let me know if additional details required.

Comment: What the ... what about try catch? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: How big is your string? [Apparently 2GB is the maximum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Excel Memory Limit of 2GB Exhausted reading a 286KB file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545217/php-excel-memory-limit-of-2gb-exhausted-reading-a-286kb-file)

Comment: try catch doesn't work

Comment: You've posted the library's source code... how about yours? Where's *your* code? I assume you're using the `read()` function somewhere... show us your code.

Comment: The document may have been corrupted.