# Redis cuts of the string when getting a serialized object back. Cant find any limits

Tags: php, mongodb, redis, limit

Using Redis to save serialized object. No error when trying to write to it. When getting the info back the string comes back cut off. Are there any settings I'm overlooking? 
It looks like the limit where I get cut off is 16 kb. Data is coming from MongoDB to Redis and then gets requested by PHP.

http://o7.no/167zDsy

the doc on the left is what I send in, on the right is what I get back. Everything after the yellow highlighted text is missing in the response on the right.

Comment: Did you try fetching from redis with the redis client and not php? I'm guessing the problem is when you deserialize the object and not in redis itself

Comment: it is a codeigniter framework library that does the fetching. it works via socket connection.

Comment: Could you post the actual code you are using?

Answer (score 3):

Doubt it's redis since max string value is huge: http://redis.io/topics/data-types

PHP max string size is huge: [What is the maximum length of a String in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php)

Smart money on the serializer/deserializer.  Check every step you can along the way (ie check directly selecting from mongoDb).