# Redis - Is there a limit on SET for datatype STRING?

Tags: string, redis, set, limit

I am using the command line interface on my mac terminal to set a long string.

SET mystring "[long string]"

Now the issue is this. When i copy from my text editor the long string into the cli, the pasted string gets cut off at 4,066 characters.

I thought it could be the copy/paste buffer size of the mac terminal but i can paste stings alot longer outside of redis-cli.

And its no where near the 512 Megabytes limit for a STRING in redis.

This is similar to another questions but not the same steps.
[Redis cuts of the string when getting a serialized object back. Cant find any limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807498/redis-cuts-of-the-string-when-getting-a-serialized-object-back-cant-find-any-li)

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

redis-cli uses [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) custom library for terminal input, which happens to have hard-coded input buffer size of 4096 bytes: [linenoise.c:101](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/deps/linenoise/linenoise.c#L101). You may want to write down your Redis command into a file and execute it with `redis-cli --eval`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-x` option to read value from stdin

```
redis-cli -x -h localhost -p 6379 set my-key < /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to use [APPEND](https://redis.io/commands/append) command. Though some effort is required to break the long string. That can be done using notepad++ see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1088622/notepad-split-line-after-given-number-of-characters).

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set greet hello
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> APPEND greet " world"
(integer) 11
127.0.0.1:6379> get greet
"hello world"
```