# How to change the limit of a string's max lengt?

Tags: php, large-data

The title tells everything, can i change the limit of a strings length? I've checked this [Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php) on stackoverflow, and it only tells that there is a limit, but how can i change it?

I've tried changing the memory limit using PHP like this:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

But it didn't work...

Comment: It doesn't say that it can be changed, therefore it can't.

Comment: So max length of a string is 2GB, that's it?

Comment: That's what the documentation says, so yeah that's it. If you need a bigger string you are most likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you have one string larger than 2GB which you want to put in your code and it should still make sense?

Comment: Should i delete this post or what am i supposed to do with this question?

Comment: Pretty certain its a hard limit. Why would you want this?

Comment: I am making a php-library that will read/edit files... and i was just wondering if there was a way to extend the limit.

Comment: What am i supposed to do with this post then? Just let it stay unanswered?

Comment: Sorry, idk much about stackoverflows 'rules'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: string can be as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)

and also:

> The string in PHP is implemented as an array of bytes and an integer indicating the length of the buffer. It has no information about how those bytes translate to characters, leaving that task to the programmer.

That integer is probably the limit.