# Why is my string stopping after 2995 characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query generated by PHP and it is stored in a string.

The amount of data to be inserted is quite large. When I run the query to insert the data into the database nothing happens. When I copy the string into a instance of vim and save the file as `*.php`, only the first ~2995 characters are highlighted in the string.

Even if I delete lines from the first 2995 characters, the next lines in the string are highlighted so that the first ~2995 characters are always highlighted.

I thought at first that there was a maximum string length, [but found it was 2GB in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php) which my string is definitely not.

I don’t know if it's helpful, but the string follows the format

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name(Field1, Field2) VALUES('value1', 'value2'),......
```

**NOTE:** All quotes in the insertion values have been escaped or removed so that should not cause a problem.

Comment: What is the size of the column you are trying to insert into in your database?

Comment: @Fluffeh Sorry I don't understand what you mean by size of column

Comment: Is the column you are trying to insert into a text, a varchar, a tinytext data type? It might be that the database is simply putting in what it can - then ignoring whatever else there is in your variable.

Comment: its varchar(20), but I have checked all the lengths are less than 20 before creating the string.

Comment: Do you have any control codes in the string you're trying to insert? I'm thinking you have something like an embedded CR/LF/EOL/SOMETHING char in there that's prematurely ending the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with `max_allowed_packet` size in your `my.cnf`. More [details here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

The details below mention using the `mysqld` from the command line to adjust this. But if possible it is best to just go straight into the `my.cnf` file and adjust `max_allowed_packet` in there. For example on a few servers I manage that use InnoDB, I set that value to `max_allowed_packet=64M`.

> The server's default max_allowed_packet value is 1MB. You can increase
>   this if the server needs to handle big queries (for example, if you
>   are working with big BLOB columns). For example, to set the variable
>   to 16MB, start the server like this:
>
> ```
> shell> mysqld --max_allowed_packet=16M
> ```
>
> You can also use an option file to set `max_allowed_packet`. For
>   example, to set the size for the server to 16MB, add the following
>   lines in an option file:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> max_allowed_packet=16M
> ```
>
> It is safe to increase the value of this variable because the extra
>   memory is allocated only when needed. For example, mysqld allocates
>   more memory only when you issue a long query or when mysqld must
>   return a large result row. The small default value of the variable is
>   a precaution to catch incorrect packets between the client and server
>   and also to ensure that you do not run out of memory by using large
>   packets accidentally.

**EDIT:** I also found another setting that might help, [`net_buffer_length`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length):

> Each client thread is associated with a connection buffer and result
>   buffer. Both begin with a size given by `net_buffer_length` but are
>   dynamically enlarged up to `max_allowed_packet` bytes as needed. The
>   result buffer shrinks to `net_buffer_length` after each SQL statement.
>
> This variable should not normally be changed, but if you have very
>   little memory, you can set it to the expected length of statements
>   sent by clients. If statements exceed this length, the connection
>   buffer is automatically enlarged. The maximum value to which
>   `net_buffer_length` can be set is 1MB.

The default for `net_buffer_length` is 16384 bytes which is 0.015625MB which then is 16KB. Try adjusting that value & try again. Maybe something like 524288 bytes which is 512 KB or 131072 bytes which is 128 KB. What you need to know is `net_buffer_length` is connected directly to `mysqldump` line lengths. So this could be it.

Comment: The size of the string is 1/10 of the size of the max allowed packet value.

Comment: the default is ~1MB, but my string is not 1MB long.

Comment: yes, I did SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'.

Comment: I get 16384, is this too small?

Comment: tried that with set global net_buffer_length=524288, and ran the code again with no change

Comment: Ok, Tnx for your help