# Is there a maximum number of lines in a php string/JS alert box?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to output some array data (>30.000 indexes) in php using a JavaScript alert box. So I create the string in a for loop containing all of my data with

```
$content .= '\\n' . data[$i];
```

Then I want to output the data using

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('$content');
</script>";
```

I'm just wondering what the maximum number of lines is that you can input in a php string or a javascript alert box.
I know it won't display 30.000 lines but what is the maximum number?

Comment: You could use the JS join() method for concatenating arrays: `data.join("\\n")`

Comment: Not at all an answer, but an alert box is imo totally the wrong tool for the job

Comment: I'm trying to limit the maximum from my for loop. I just want to check how many lines I can display to test the output ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A string can be **as large as 2GB.**

For more detailed information, check this post:

[What is the maximum length of a String in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: And yes, this question looks like a duplicate.

Comment: I closed it as a dupe which mostly contains info about the JS side, so you remark about php is still useful. Although if you put a 2GB string in a alert big you probably have bigger problems :P