# PHP: insert a short string into a long one without allocating much memory?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

Consider this code:

```
$position = ...
$data = substr($data, 0, $position) . $insertion . substr($data, $position);
```

Normally `$data` in the case of the script being discussed is no larger than 2-3 MB. But it happened that a user who would like to use the script tried to use it for `$data` with the size of about 17 MB and got

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17687776 bytes) in //index.php on line 179'

where line 179 is the second one shown above (`$data = ...`), 33554432 bytes = 32 MB and 17687776 > 16 MB. Now I'm assuming that the problem is memory is allocated for both `$data` *and* `substr($data, 0, $position)` and `substr($data, $position)`. I'm aware of [the memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php) and suggested them to try to increase it. However, I wonder if I can optimize this so that we don't need the memory limit to be more than twice larger than `$data`.

So my question is: is there some clever way to insert `$insertion` to minimize memory usage? (not to store `$data` in memory twice) How about the case where `substr($data, $position)` is relatively small?

Answer (score 4):

Your current implementation depends on target position. It most memory-efficient if the position near to end of data. Worst case is inserting into begin of the data.

Mini-benchmark for example:

```php
$data      = str_repeat('abcde', 500000);
$insertion = 'abc';
$position  = 0;

$data = substr($data, 0, $position) . $insertion . substr($data, $position);

echo memory_get_peak_usage(), "\n";
```

Script above show peak usage is 7868728 bytes (on my machine). If I set the `$position = strlen($data) / 2` then it prints 6619424. If append the string at the end of data (`$position = strlen($data)`) then it prints 5365720.

(**Update**: memory consumption of code above also [depends](https://3v4l.org/UV3Is) on the PHP version)

But PHP already has efficient function for replace text within a portion of a string: **[`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)**:

```php
$data = substr_replace($data, $insertion, $position, 0);
```

In all cases, this requires as much memory as the implementation above (through concatenation of `substr()` results) *in best case*.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful indeed, especially the way to test (using `memory_get_peak_usage()`), but I got some controversial results of tests, so I'll accept the answer later when I'm sure all this is correct (actually, I'm looking for *why* and have to get a more detailed picture). Definitely upvoted.

Comment: Oh, you are right! https://3v4l.org/UV3Is - looks like memory consumption in this case also depends on version of PHP (may be latest version has some related optimizations?). Thanks, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Nice! Needed Memory is the same, but substr_replace is twice as fast. (benchmark for script time)