# The maximum number of characters of the md5 input

Tags: php, md5

How many maximum characters can be in the `$string` variable?

```
$string = 'test';

echo md5($string);
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can easily go read up on that on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: @CBroe, I don't see that there is an answer to my question.

Comment: Sorry, misread what you meant. There is no limit (other than that PHP & memory limit might dictate.) Your comment under the currently existing answer, _“how many characters can be stored in it”_, makes rather little sense though - this does not “store” any data, this calculates a hash.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, perhaps there isn't a specific limit beyond [PHP maximum string size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A md5 is always 32 characters long, i think you can limit it

Note: As of PHP 7.0.0, there are no particular restrictions regarding the length of a string on 64-bit builds. On 32-bit builds and in earlier versions, a string can be as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)

[you can find doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I don't mean the length of md5, but how many characters can be stored in it

Comment: Your input can be as long as possible in your current programming language

Comment: Note: As of PHP 7.0.0, there are no particular restrictions regarding the length of a string on 64-bit builds. On 32-bit builds and in earlier versions, a string can be as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate MD5 hashes of huge strings, perhaps you want to use files so you can save memory and calculate the hash with [md5_file()](https://php.net/md5_file).

I've made a quick test with a 527 GB disk image (PHP/7.4 x64 on Windows 10). It was painfully slow (in my case the bottleneck was the file being on a slow disk) but the script had a [peak memory usage](https://php.net/memory_get_peak_usage) of 2 MB.